# Loop optimization

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review

I wrote this to generate a 6D distribution of particles.

```
Bunch = {};
Do[
  Particle = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  tempX = { RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitX]]], 
               RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitX]]]};
  tempY = { RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitY]]], 
               RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitY]]]};
  coordS = {PhiS + \[Pi], BucketHeightP};
  While[Abs[coordS[[1]]] >= (PhiS + \[Pi]) || 
               Abs[coordS[[2]]] >= \[Delta][coordS[[1]]],
    coordS = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[PhiS, BlengthRad]], 
               RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, MAXDPP ]]};];
  coordX = {XCO + Sqrt[BetaX] tempX[[1]] + Dx coordS[[2]], 
               XPCO + (-(AlphaX/Sqrt[BetaX]) tempX[[1]] + 
               1/Sqrt[BetaX] tempX[[2]]) + Dpx coordS[[2]]};
  coordY = {YCO + Sqrt[BetaY] tempY[[1]], 
               YPCO - AlphaY/Sqrt[BetaY] tempY[[1]] + 1/Sqrt[BetaY] tempY[[2]]};
  Particle = Flatten[{coordX, coordY, coordS}];
  Bunch = Append[Bunch, Particle],
{i, 1, 20000}];
```

I don't think the details are important. I call 6 times `RandomVariate` which I'm afraid is quite inefficient. Would you suggest some major improvement ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet is to remove the procedural programming `Do`, `While` and `Append` Statements, building lists with `Append` is not quick. Then embrace a functional programming approach on which Mathematica thrives. Making use of constructs like `Transpose`, `Part`, `Nest`, `Map`, `Table` and `Fold`. These are generally much faster and lead to eventually to less buggy code.

If machine precision numbers are enough you can look at using `Compile`.

There are many approaches, but you could try something along these lines:-

There is no need to initialise Particle in Mathematica.

You can eliminate the `Do` loop and  its 80,000 thousand calls to `RandomVariate`
by just two calls.

```
dimensions=2; numParticles=20000;
XYs = 
Transpose[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitX]], {numParticles,dimensions}],
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitY]], {numParticles,dimensions}]}];
```

This gives you a list of pairs of Xs and Ys of length `numParticles`.

You could then write a set of functions to compute `coordS`, `coordsX`, `coordsY`, say `C[]`, `cX[]`, `cY[]`.

Then combine `Table` and `NestWhile`.

The basic form for `NestWhile` is

```
NestWhile[function, initial state, terminating condition]
```

The terminating condition is checked, 'function' is is applied to 'initial state' producing a result.

The result is held in a variable known as `#`. `#` may have several components. These components are accessed by the part notation, `#[[1]]`, `#[[2]]` and so on.

The terminating condition is then checked and if true, result is then given to function to evaluate.

This produces a new result ... and so on. It's basically recursion.
The trick is to make the 'initial condition' have the same structure as the result of applying 'function'. Function may actually be a compound list of results gained by using several functions. And sometimes you need to 'pad' an element of the list, as it can be used to hold the parameters for the nest.

In your case perhaps something to compute the `{coordX, coordY, coordS, XY }`.

The shape of the code would look something like this

```
res =   
Table[
 NestWhile[{C[],cX[#[[1,1],#[[3,2]]],Cy[#[[2]]]}&,
 {p[[1]],p[[2]],{PhiS + Pi, BucketHeightP}},
 Abs[#[[3,1]]] >= (PhiS + Pi) ||  Abs[#[[3,2]]] >= d[#[[3,1]]] &], 
{p,XYs}]
```

Assuming PhiS  BucketHeightP do not change between iterations.

This is just a roughed out solution and probably skips over some details and could definitely be improved but should help you towards a faster implementation and give you a flavour of the functional approach.

I hope you can see that the form of the solution is essentially a `Table` command with a `NestWhile`and 3 auxiliary functions. You could even insert the initial creation of the variable XYs into Table command, but that would have just reduced comprehension in this case.

This is typical of what functional programming brings to the party. Very concise programs with a high level of abstraction.

One way of looking at it is that you start with your initial data and then apply some functional transforms to arrive at your final data. This avoids a lot of the bugs introduced by procedural programs that have lots of state information held in global variables. State information that often gets inadvertently corrupted.

Apologies, but this isn't debugged code, but a template solution - so there might be a few niggles to iron out before it flies.

Further performance tuning tips can be found at:
[tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721171/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/4723969#4723969)

Answer (score 8):

Minor improvement:
`RandomVariate` accepts a second argument with the number of elements you want to create. 
So your assignments to `tempX`, etc, are equivalent to

```
tempX = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitX]], 2];
tempY = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[EmitY]], 2];
```

Comment: I did that, thanks !

Answer (score 7):

As you expect, it's much faster to call `RandomVariate` fewer times. In fact, it'd be much much faster to call it only once at the beginning, generating large arrays and then operating on them:

```
In[20]:= Bunch = {};
Timing[Do[
  Particle = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]],
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]],
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]],
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]],
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]],
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]};
  Append[Bunch, Particle],
  {i, 1, 200000}]]
Out[21]= {2.92156, Null}

In[22]:= Bunch = {};
Timing[Do[
  Particle = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 6];
  Append[Bunch, Particle],
  {i, 1, 200000}]]
Out[23]= {0.873262, Null}

In[24]:= Timing[Bunch = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {20000, 6}];]
Out[25]= {0.006057, Null}
```

In your example, it's slightly different because you're not calling it a predefined number of times due to your `While` loop. However, this optimization can still be done for then `tempX` and `tempY` variables, which can become fixed-sized arrays generated by one or two calls to `RandomVariate` before the loop.

After that, further optimization depends on how many iterations the `While` loop does on average. If it's rarely iterated (i.e. in most cases the condition is true after the first iteration), then you can perform your calculations on a big array, then go over it and only “fix” the values that need fixing. Anything you can put in array form, outside a `Do` loop, will go much faster.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, it's generally not very efficient to create a table using `Append` repeatedly. This is because every time you call `p = Append[p, exp]`, Mathematica creates a new copy of the list. A more efficient way would be to use `Table` instead, i.e.

```
Bunch = Table[ code; Particle, {i, 20000}];
```

Comment: I did that too !